# Proof of $\mathcal{F}\approx\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ using elementary notations and Cantor Bernstein Theorem?

Tags: solution-verification, cardinals, alternative-proof

**Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}$. My math textbook wants me to use Cantor-Bernstein Theorem.**

**Question: Using Cantor-Bernstein Theroem, prove $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.**

Proof:

The definition of $\mathcal{F}$ represent all subsets of $\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\}$. Hence $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\})$.

Suppose we create a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\}$. If $f(x)=(x,1)$, then it is automatically one-to-one. Hence, $|\mathbb{N}|\le|\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\}|$. Therefore, $|\mathcal{P}{(\mathbb{N})}|\le|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\})|$. Hence, $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})|
\le|\mathcal{F}|$.

Now suppose we create $g:\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\}\to\mathbb{N}$. If $g=xy$, then if $x_1y_1=x_2y_2$ then $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$. Hence $g$ is one-to-one. Hence $|\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\}|\le|\mathbb{N}|$. Therefore, $|\mathcal{F}|\le|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})|$.

Hence using Cantor-Bernstein Theorem, $|\mathcal{F}|=|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})|$. Therefore $\mathcal{F}\approx\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$

**Is my proof correct? If not, how can we improve it? (If you don't understand my proof, make your own answer.)**

Comment: You have $\mathcal{F}\neq\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\})$, so the very first statement isn't true.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Show me why $\mathcal{F}\neq\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\})$?

Comment: @Arbuja: Just write down the definitions. Not every subset of $\Bbb N\times\{0,1\}$ is a function.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I posted an answer. I believe this is more elementary.

Comment: @Arbuja: What do you mean "more elementary"? How can ${\cal F\neq P}(\Bbb N\times\{0,1\})$ be disproved in a more elementary way than noting that some of the elements of $\mathcal P(\Bbb N\times\{0,1\})$ are not functions whose domain is $\Bbb N$?

Comment: @AsafKarigala I’m talking about the question in my post. I figured out $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\})$

Comment: But that's not related to my comment, is it now? My comment was a reply to your question to Brian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof:

The definition of $\mathcal{F}$ is one of the subsets of $\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\}$. Hence $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\})$.

Suppose we create $g:\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\}\to\mathbb{N}$. If $g(x,y)=2^x(2y+1)$; then, if $2^{(x_1)}{(2y_1+1)}=2^{(x_2)}{(2y_2+1)}$, then $2^{x_1}=2^{x_2}$ and $2y_1+1=2y_2+1$. Therefore $x_1=x_2$ and $2y_1=2y_2$; and therefore $y_1=y_2$.  This means $g$ is one-to-one. Therefore, $|\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\}|\le|\mathbb{N}|$. This means $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\})|\le|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})|$, moreover; since $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\})$, $|F|\le|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\})|\le|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})|$ giving $|\mathcal{F}|\le|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})|$.

Now consider $f:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\to\mathcal{F}$, we can construct $f(A)=\chi_A$ where  $A\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and $\chi_{A}:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is the characterisitic function. If $f(A)=f(B)$ then $\chi_{A}=\chi_{B}$. Therefore, $A=B$. Since $f$ is injective, $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})|\le|\mathcal{F}|$.

Using Cantor-Bernstein Theorem, $|\mathcal{F}|=|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})|$. Therefore $\mathcal{F}\approx\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$

**Is my proof correct? If not, how can we improve it?**

Comment: Your first sentence still isn't true, but you don't use it anywhere, so can just erase it or edit it.  More importantly, $g$ is not injective and $f(A) \not\in\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Can you state why it isn’t true or try and improve on my proof rather than continuous point out mistakes.

Comment: $g(x,y)=xy$ is almost never injective.  For instance, $5 \times 4= 10\times 2$ but $5\neq 10$ and $4\neq 2$ so there will never be a time you can write "$x_1y_1 = x_2y_2$ implies $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$" without an argument for why it's true in this case.  In your case, specifically, $g(n,0) = 0$ for every $n$, so it's far from injective.  Two common options for defining injective maps $g : \mathbb{N} \times \{0,1\} \to \mathbb{N}$ are either by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic or by even-odd parity.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I corrected g. How do I correct f?

Comment: I see you have changed your $g$ so that it's injective now.  I'm glad to see you've fixed the $g$ but the same criticism applies to your proof.  You need to give a reason for how we know $g$ is injective.  Right now, you're essentially begging the question (which is still invalid even with a true conclusion)

Comment: For $f$, your $f(A)$ is currently a constant function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{F},$ such that $f(A)(n) = \chi_A \in \mathcal{F}$ for every $n$.  This is why I said $f(A) \not\in \mathcal{F}$.  Instead, just define $f(A) = \chi_A$.

Comment: As some help for showing $g$ is injective, note your $g$ is also given by $g(x,y) = 2^x3^y$ which is a form we can directly apply the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to.

Comment: As a final note, some advice: your original comment here can easily be read as "show me how to fix it instead of just saying where it's wrong".  Depending on who you talk to, this may come off as a combination of lazy and disrespectful, because you're seemingly not considering what was actually said and specifically devaluing their help.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I apologize for offending you. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Cantor-Bernstein-Schröder is overkill. If $X$ is any set, and $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the set of all functions $X \to \{0,1\}$, then the map $$\wp(X) \ni A \mapsto \chi_A \in \mathcal{F}$$ is a bijection, where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$, defined by $\chi_A(x)=1$ if $x \in A$ and $\chi_A(x)=0$ if $x \not\in A$.

- Surjectivity: if $f \in \mathcal{F}$, then $f = \chi_{f^{-1}[\{1\}]}$.
- Injectivity: if $A,B \in \wp(X)$ and $A \neq B$, there is $x \in (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$, so $\chi_A(x)\neq \chi_B(x)$ says that $\chi_A \neq \chi_B$ (as functions).

Comment: My textbook states I have to use the Cantor Bernstein Theorem. Moreover, I’m a beginner student, I can understand your proof but explain your proof as though it is elementary.